# Home and End keys don't work when popup created on page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If you take a look at [this page](http://www.pricewombat.com/price-tracking) you'll see a bunch of products in containers. If you click on one of the products, a popup will open that will (most likely) have a greater height than the browser window and so a scrollbar will be shown.

After a popup is opened, the Home and End keys do not make the element scroll when pressed. However, if you click in the popup, then the keys work.

I've tried calling `.focus()` and `.click()` on the popup after opening it, but the Home and End keys still don't have any effect until I click in the popup with my mouse.

Why don't the Home and End keys make the element scroll when pressed, and how can I get them to work?

Comment: need to understand how `position:fixed` works. Also difference between page scrolling and element scrolling

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`focus()` won't actually give keyboard focus to an element unless the element is focusable.  Interactive elements like `input` and `textarea` are focusable, but by default a `div` is not.  However, you can make it focusable by setting its [`tabIndex` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/tabIndex) (or [`tabindex` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex)).

When I load your page and type the following into console:

```
$(".productPopupContainer").prop("tabIndex", "-1");
$(".productPopupContainer").focus();
```

The Home and End keys begin to work even though I haven't clicked in the popup.  (I'm using the latest version of Chrome on a Mac, btw).

The [jQuery documentation page for focus()](http://api.jqueryui.com/focusable-selector/) has a good explanation of how this works.

**FUN FACT**: If you don't set `tabIndex` on an element but read that property, you'll get -1:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("#anything");
console.log(elem.tabIndex); // prints -1
```

But internally in the browser, the value is actually not defined, because explicitly setting it to -1 makes it focusable, when it wasn't previously.  This means you can actually do this to make an element focusable without affecting its tab order:

```
elem.tabIndex = elem.tabIndex;
```